# How to reboot a host machine via python script, and on boot resume the script?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, debian

I'm writing a python script on Linux (debian) to install a few things, reboot, and then do more things.

I'm not sure if it's possible, but would I be able to say,

run all of my installers, reboot and resume my script from where it left off?

I would like for the user to not have to do anything (even log onto the machine, if at all possible)

Oh! Also, is there a way to keep(or Store) variables without storing them in plaintext?

Thanks!

Comment: I would split the script into 2 scripts: one pre-boot, and one post-boot. You can have the pre-boot script add the post-boot script into the init.d folder so it will execute at boot time. Take a look at https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

Comment: I figured this would be the *easiest* way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more way to execute your script at booting time by adding below line to root's crontab

@reboot /usr/bin/python /root/simple.py

simple.py  -- script need to be executed.